# Wordpress uses backed-up theme files instead of customized file. (solved by myself // little how-to)

Tags: wordpress, debugging, themes, customization, custom-wordpress-pages

I just wrote a long and detailed question and when I was about to submit it, I fixed the problem by myself. The problem did cost me about 5 hours and now I will just post this little explanation, so maybe it helps others and they will not feel as stupid as I do right now.
In my defense: I do not have that much experience with this system.

## What was the Problem? When did it show up?

Before I change a file on the server, I always duplicate it and change the file name to `originalFileName_yyyymmdd_hhmm.php` (filename + date + time). I want to keep track of the changes, and when we launch the website, I wanted to do a local backup and then delete them from the server.

Let's say, in the folder of the active theme there is a file called `home.php`.
It is a template file, which means that you can select it as a template for a page when editing it in the backend of WordPress.

I duplicated it and called the new file `home_20180301_2300.php`.
Then I edited the `home.php`, but the changes were not displayed on the website.
I checked for any known cache issue, but that was not the problem. So I installed a debugging plugin ([Template Debugger](https://de.wordpress.org/plugins/quick-edit-template-link/)) to see which files are used by the server to create the website.

Wordpress used the `home_20180301_2300.php` instead of the `home.php` and I did not know why. When I deleted `home_20180301_2300.php` WordPress did NOT use `home.php` It just took the standard template instead.

## What I think what happened

In the last moment before submitting this question I realized what happened:

In the process of working, there was a situation where I deleted the `home.php` and then edited the page in the backend. WordPress could not find the `home.php`, which was set as the template for this page. BUT it found `home_20180301_2300.php` and used it. (Because WordPress is smart [sometimes {not a joke}]). When `home.php` was back in its place, WordPress did not care. It looks like as long as there is no problem, WordPress does not search for other (or newer, or better suiting) files. It still used `home_20180301_2300.php`, because it worked. That's why my changes in `home.php` did not have any effect. `home.php` was ignored.

## The Solution

I had to delete `home_20180301_2300.php`, open the page in edit mode and select `home.php` as the template again. WordPress did not find `home_20180301_2300.php`, "BUT HEY! There is `home.php`, my old friend, so I can use it", WordPress said and they happily lived together for the rest of their time.

## Feel free to comment!

I am sure my explanation is quite simple and not showing the whole picture. If anyone knows better, I would be glad to hear it. Better knowledge of the problem and the way WordPress works can help me and others to better understand future issues.

Peace out,
Nils

Comment: People will probably downvote this a lot since it's not a question, but I appreciated the information.

Comment: Already thought that this could happen.
"Haters will hate" - it's always the same.

Comment: @Nils, after a while, questions without answers and without positive votes get deleted by [roomba](https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba). So please format your question as a question only, and give it your self-answer separately.